# PHP Upload file via session.upload_progress.name

Tags: java, php

I´m trying to upload a file via session.upload_progress.name - it works fine on some files, but if a file is "bigger" f.ex. 13MB, the script stops. The problem is NOT because of the file size - it´s more about the time limit i think. If i use a faster internet connection, it works fine. My webhoster is Strato - does anyone have a solution?

This is my code:

```
    <?php session_start();
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Upload CSV Dateien</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.form.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <article>
        <header>
            <h1>UPLOAD Import Dateien</h1>
        </header>

        <section>
            <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="upload_form">
            <!--
                Dieses Feld ist wichtig. PHP benötigt dies für die Zuordnung.
                Der Wert (Value) ist für uns später wichtig um auf die globale $_SESSION zuzugreifen
            -->
                <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo ini_get("session.upload_progress.name"); ?>" value="test">
                <div>
                    <label for="datei1">Bitte Datei zum hochladen auswählen: </label>
                    <p></p>
                    <input name="file1" type="file" id="datei1">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input name="upload_start" type="submit" value="Hochladen">
                    <input name="abbrechen" type="button" value="Abbrechen" id="abbrechen">
                </div>
            </form>
        </section> 

        <section>
            <div>
                <progress max="1" value="0" id="fortschritt"></progress>
                <p id="fortschritt_txt"></p>
            </div>
        </section>   
    </article>

    <script>

        var intervalID = 0;

        $(document).ready(function(e) {

            $('#upload_form').submit(function(e) {

                if($('#datei1').val() == ''){
                    e.preventDefault(); //Event abbrechen

                    return false;
                }

                intervalID = setInterval(function() {
                    $.getJSON('fortschritt.php', function(data){

                        if(data)
                        {
                            $('#fortschritt').val(data.bytes_processed / data.content_length);
                            $('#fortschritt_txt').html('Fortschritt '+ Math.round((data.bytes_processed / data.content_length)*100) + '%');
                        }
                    });
                }, 1000); //Zeitintervall auf 1s setzen

                $('#upload_form').ajaxSubmit({    
                                                success: function()
                                                {
                                                    $('#fortschritt').val('1');
                                                    $('#fortschritt_txt').html('Fertig');
                                                    clearInterval(intervalID);  
                                                    location.reload(); 
                                                },                                                
                                                error:    function()
                                                {
                                                    $('#fortschritt').val('1');
                                                    $('#fortschritt_txt').html('Ein Fehler ist aufgetreten');
                                                    clearInterval(intervalID);    
                                                }
                                            });
                e.preventDefault(); //Event Abbrechen

            });

            $('#abbrechen').click(function(e) {
                $.ajax("fortschritt.php?cancel=true");
                $('#fortschritt').val('1');
                $('#fortschritt_txt').html('Upload abgebrochen');

                clearInterval(intervalID);
            });
        });

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

And this the upload.php

```
<?php

session_start();

/*
* Session-Upload-Progress ist leer
* durch die Option session.upload_progress.enabled = On
*/
var_dump($_SESSION);

/*
* Übliches Format von $_FILES
*/
var_dump($_FILES);

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file1']['tmp_name'],'../import/'.$_FILES['file1']['name']);

/*
* Wenn abgebrochen
*/
if($_FILES['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION)
    echo "Datei abgebrochen";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please put set_time_limit to 0 before starting file upload and it will set for unlimited time execution and the script will not stop until finishing upload. (But it is best to set some time limit for uploading to avoid server issues.

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

Comment: I editet my post - where do i have to add this set_time_limit? I tried it to put it in the beginning of the upload.php, but without any success

Comment: in which file? upload.php? I tried it without any success

Comment: Then it will be the problem of host. If it is a shared hosting there is a chance to limit the php execution time to avoid server crashing.

Comment: Do I have to put it in the index.php or upload.php? Both start with a session start